# Хранимая процедура для вычисляемого поля с IF

Tags: sql

```
Понимаю что присваивать значения как я этого делаю наверное нельзя подскажите хоть немного

как с IF можно работать в моем случае 
    CREATE PROCEDURE tekStoimOS/* текущая стоимость основного средства*/
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @@mesiac int,@@god int ;
UPDATE dbo.tObjectOS 
SET @@mesiac =  MONTH(GETDATE()) - MONTH(tObjectOS.dDateVvodOS),
    @@god=YEAR(GETDATE())-YEAR(tObjectOS.dDateVvodOS)
begin 
 IF(@@mesiac<0)/*если месяц получается с минусом, то 12+(минусовое чило),присваиваем чило месяца пользования*/
 BEGIN
  SELECT @@mesiac= 12+@@mesiac,  @@god=@@god-1;/*год -1 так как месяц с минусом*/
  END;
  SET
 /*теперь расчитываем текущую стоимость = первоначальная стоимость + сумма амортизации лет + месяцев + если есть записи в таблице обслуживание то сумму поля стоимость обслуживание прибавить)*/
 tStoimOS.mTekStoimOS= tStoimOS.mPervStoimOS(tStoimOS.GodSumAmort * @@god +tStoimOS.GodSumAmort/12*@@mesiac)+
  SUM( SELECT tObsluzhOS.mStoimObsluzhOS
  FROM(tSoimOS INTER JOIN StoimObsluzhOS tSoimOS.iKodOS= StoimObsluzhOS.StoimObsluzhOS))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у вас амортизация рассчитывается помесячно, поэтому нет необходимости так сложно рассчитывать срок в месяца (тем более что алгоритм неточный). В transact-sql для этого есть функция DATEDIFF. 
Далее - не очень понял, почему амортизация плюсуется к начальной стоимости актива. По моему разумению использование актива уменьшает его текущую стоимость.
Далее - весь текст процедуры сомнительный, Вам нужно подучить синтаксис

Примерно это может выглядеь так:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE tekStoimOS
AS
UPDATE tObjectOS
SET mTekStoimOS = mPervStoimOS  * (1+GodSumAmort*datediff(month, dDateVVodOS, GETDATE())/12)+
(SELECT SUM(mStoimObsluzhOS) FROM StoimObsluzhOS S WHERE S.iKodOS = tObjectOS.iKodOS)
```

ну и всё